# Directed Acyclic Graphs in Emacs Lisp

Tags: list, data-structures

Emacs Lisp has support for lists (naturally), association lists, and property lists, vectors, and hash tables. Does it have support for directed acyclic graphs (DAGs)?

I have not found a DAG API in the native Emacs, and searching the package repository has not uncovered anything either. Does Emacs have a DAG API, or has one not been written yet?

Comment: I challenge you to find a programming language with out-of-the-box support for these.

Comment: wasamasa: Downloading a working library, is of course, acceptable. However I have not found one in ELPA, MELPA, or Marmalade.